working example of passing data by reference to array in tradestation Easy Language
Can someone have working example of passing data by reference to array in tradestation Easy Language ? I want to have a function which load number of prices to array and returns this array to main code like below but it not compiles
function loadarray
Inputs: DataTS(NumericSeries), lookBackBars(NumericSimple), loadarray1[300](NumericArrayRef);

vars: ii(0);
//Array:loadarray1 [300](0);

for ii=0 to lookBackBars 
    begin
    loadarray1[ii] = DataTS[ii];
    end;
loadarray = loadarray1; 

